# Prove $\varphi(u)=\frac{e^u-u-1}{u^2}$ is nondecreasing for all $u\in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

We have
$$
\varphi^\prime(u)=\frac{e^u\cdot u^2+u^2-2ue^u+2u}{u^4}.
$$

To prove $\varphi$ is nondecreasing for all $u$, it suffices to prove
$$
f_1(u)=e^u\cdot u^2+u^2-2ue^u+2u \geq 0 \quad \forall u\in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Let
$$
f_2(u)=f_1(u)=e^u\cdot u^2-4ue^u+2u-2e^u+2.
$$
ButI still fail to get any useful information to prove that $\varphi$ is nondecreasing.

Comment: Hint: $f_1(u)\ge 0$ iff $(ue^u+u-2e^u+2)u\ge 0$. Prove $f_1(u)/u$ is also increasing and has a root zero.

Comment: Are you going to accept any of the answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{{e^u  - u - 1}}{{u^2 }} = \int_0^1 {(1 - s)e^{us} ds} 
$$
for all non-zero real $u$. The right-hand side is clearly an increasing function of $u$.

Comment: (+1) that was a clever thing to do!

Answer (score 1):

Observing the numerator of $\varphi$ is the remainder of the Taylor expansion while the denominator is the power of the remainder, I derive through a general proposition. [The $k$'th order remainder of a Taylor expansion of a function $f(x)$ around $x=0$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Derivation_for_the_integral_form_of_the_remainder) which is just repeated integration by parts on $$f(x)=f(0)-\int_{t=0}^x f^{(1)}(t)\,d(x-t)$$ is
\begin{align}
k!R_k(x) &= \int_0^x f^{(k+1)}(t)(x-t)^k\,dt \\
&= x^{k+1}\int_0^1 f^{(k+1)}(xs)(1-s)^k\,ds
\end{align}
where we replace $t=:xs$. So the monotonicity and convexity of $k!\frac{R_k(x)}{x^{k+1}}$ inherit directly from those of $f^{(k+1)}$ via the preservation of monotonicity and convexity by addition and positive scaling.

Applying this general proposition to the problem at hand $f(x)=e^x$. $\forall k\in \overline{\mathbf Z^-}$, $f^{(k+1)}(x)=e^x$ which is increasing and convex, thus $k!\frac{R_k(x)}{x^{k+1}}$ is increasing and convex.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
u^3\varphi'(u)&=(1+e^u)u+2(1-e^u) \\
&= 2(1+e^u)\bigg(\frac u2+\frac{e^{-\frac u2}-e^{\frac u2}}{e^{-\frac u2}+e^{\frac u2}}\bigg) \\
&=2(1+e^u)(x-\tanh x)
\end{align}
where $x=\frac u2$. It is easy to see
$$x> \tanh x,\,\forall x>0.$$
Together with $\tanh(-x)=-\tanh x$, we see $u^3\varphi'(u)$ has the same sign as $u$. The desired result is obtained.

Comment: You are missing a prime on the $\phi$.

Comment: @Gary: Thank you for spotting the typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another proof.

\begin{align}
u^3\varphi'(u)&=(1+e^u)u+2(1-e^u) \\
&= 2u\Big(\frac{1+e^u}2-\frac{e^u-1}u\Big) \\
&= 2u\Big(\frac{f(0)+f(u)}2-\frac{1}u\int_0^u f(t)dt \Big) \\
&= 2u\Big(\frac{f(0)+f(u)}2-\int_0^1 f(tu)dt \Big)
\end{align}
where $f(u)=e^u$. We know
$$\int_0^1 g(t)dt\le \int_0^1 \big((1-t)g(0)+tg(1)\big)\,dt=\frac{g(0)+g(1)}2$$
if $g$ is convex. Let $g(t)=f(tu)$. Since $f(u)=e^u$ is indeed convex, we have
$\varphi'(u)\ge0, \,\forall u>0$.